# EPPlus Pivot table SubTotalFunctions produces spreadsheet error

Tags: c#, epplus

I am creating a pivot table to with data.  I create a `RowField` and attempt to add a `SubTotalFunctions` to that field.

When I open the .xlsx file, I get an error that says the file needs to be repaired.

Is this a bug or is there another option that I should be setting?

```
    using OfficeOpenXml;
    using OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable;
    
    var data = Datas();
    
    var stream = new FileStream("Data.xlsx", FileMode.Create);
    // Create the spread sheet package
    var pkg = new ExcelPackage(stream);
    
    var wsData = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
    var wsPivot = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Pivot Table");
    
    
    var dataRange = wsData.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(data, true);
    
    // Create the pivot table
    var pivotTable = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot.Cells["A1"], wsData.Cells[1,1,dataRange.End.Row, 3], "Pivot Table");
    pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[0]);  // FirstNumber
    var r = pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[1]);    // SecondNumber
    pivotTable.ColumnFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[2]);     // Text
    
    r.SubtotalTop = true;
    r.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.Sum;
    r.Sort = eSortType.Ascending;
    r.Compact = true;
    
    r.Outline = true;
    pkg.Save();
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
    
    IEnumerable<Data> Datas()
    {
        return new List<Data>
        {
            new()
            {
                Text = "red",
                FirstNumber = 0,
                SecondNumber = 10
            },
            new()
            {
                Text = "red",
                FirstNumber = 1,
                SecondNumber = 10
            },
            new()
            {
                Text = "blue",
                FirstNumber = 2,
                SecondNumber = 10
            },
            new()
            {
                Text = "blue",
                FirstNumber = 3,
                SecondNumber = 20
            },
            new()
            {
                Text = "green",
                FirstNumber = 4,
                SecondNumber = 20
            },
            new()
            {
                Text = "green",
                FirstNumber = 5,
                SecondNumber = 40
            }
        };
    }
    
    internal class Data
    {
        public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
        public int SecondNumber { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```